# how to compute field on odoo 13 sale order line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, decorator, odoo-13

I'm trying to calculate discount field on sale order line, and the method was working well in odoo 12 but in odoo 13 i get this error every time I try to add line

> sale.order.line(<NewId 0x7f3dd0d624a8>,).discount_mount

here is the what I've done

```
class discount_cycle(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order.line'

discount_mount = fields.Float(string="",  required=False , compute='discount_calculation')


@api.depends('product_id','discount','price_subtotal')
def discount_calculation(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.discount:
            if rec.product_uom_qty > 1:
                rec.discount_mount = ((rec.price_unit * rec.product_uom_qty) * (rec.discount / 100))
            else:
                rec.discount_mount = (rec.price_unit * (rec.discount / 100))
        pass
```

Note that was @api.one in odoo V 12, so how can I solve this issue and what is replacement for @api.one in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In odoo V13 you must assing the value to the computed field instead of `pass` you need to add `else` statement and assign the default value

```
     else:
             self.discount_mount = 0.0
```

I know this is clear if we don't have a discount then the field should be 0.0 but odoo want you you to do that

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a value in any case to the non-stored computed field, even if it is a falsy one, computed stored fields will keep their previous value if not assigned during the compute method, so don't rely on any expected default value.

The `api.one` decorator was removed, now it is multi-record by default. You have just to remove the decorator from your code and loop over `self` (which is already done in your example).

> If it uses the values of other fields, it should specify those fields using [depends()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields).

You need to replace `product_id` and `price_subtotal` with `price_unit` and `product_uom_qty`.

When `discount` is `0.0`, the `discount_mount` should also be `0.0` and in your expressions, you are dividing the discount by `100` then doing multiplications. If the value of the `discount` is `0.0`, it will not be a problem, the expressions will be evaluated to `0.0` and the `discount_mount` field will be set to `0.0` which mean that you can remove the `if` expression:

```
if rec.discount:
```